# C# WPF update command

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I am working with an application where user retrieves specific data from database using Text Box, Button and a Data Grid. What I want to do is that when the user retrieves data and show in Data Grid for example:

```
   Code      Product      Price     QTY   
  123456789  Coke         1.2       1
```

The user can change the qty for example 3, when the user hit the button update the database column QTY should update ( subtracting by the Data Grid column qty(3))
The code I used to retrieve data:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = test; Integrated Security = true");
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Product", con); // Using a Store Procedure.
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Barcode", txtcode.Text);
     dtg.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;//Set the DataGrid ItemSource to this new generated DataTable
     con.Open();//Open the SQL connection
     SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//Create a SqlDataReader
     while (reader.Read())//For each row that the SQL query returns do
     {
         DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();//Create new DataRow to populate the DataTable (which is currently binded to the DataGrid)
         dr[0] = reader[0];//Fill DataTable column 0 current row (Product) with reader[0] (Product from sql)
         dr[1] = reader[1];
         dr[2] = reader[2];
         dr[3] = reader[3];
         dr[4] = reader[4];
         dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);//Add the new created DataRow to the DataTable
         txtcode.Text = "";
         object sumObject;
         sumObject = dataTable.Compute("Sum(Totali)", "");
         txttot.Text = sumObject.ToString();
     }
}
```

I know the update process by using Text Box-es, but using data Grid column is new to me. If someone could tell how to update the database column also how to save on another table the results from data grid with a specific example Thanks to everyone!

Comment: are you following MVVM pattern?

Comment: No I am not using

Comment: can you upload the UI code?